# default dict in grouping

Tags: python, defaultdict

My code doesn't give me the same results as my assert function doesn't work. 
What might be the problem?

I've tried shifting the 'return d' function one tab right to shorten what the code might do and after printing 'groups1' and 'test_max_item', the output is similar. However the assert function still fails.

```
Scripts =[ { ‘a’: ‘1, ‘bnf_name’: ‘joy’, ‘items’ : 3}
{ ‘a’ :2, ‘ bnf_name’: ‘loss’, ‘ items’: 6}....]
from collections import defaultdict

def group_by_field(dictionary, grpbykey): 
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for poop in dictionary: 
        d[poop[grpbykey]].append(poop)
    return d

groups1 = group_by_field(scripts, 'bnf_name')
test_max_item = group_by_field(scripts,'bnf_name')
assert test_max_item == groups1
```

I expected no assert errors.

Comment: What is `max_item`? Did you mean `groups1`?

Comment: can you give a scripts example input?

Comment: Okay!!! Edited and given. Sorry for the wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code lacks readability (x100). Anyway, maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
from collections import defaultdict


scripts = [{'a': 1, 'bnf_name': 'joy', 'items': 3}, {'a': 2, ' bnf_name': 'loss', ' items': 6}]
reverse_scripts = [{val:key for val,key in d.iteritems()} for d in scripts]


def group_by_field(dictionaries, grpbykey):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for dictionary in dictionaries:
        if grpbykey in dictionary:
            d[grpbykey].append(dictionary[grpbykey])
    return d


groups1 = group_by_field(reverse_scripts, 'bnf_name')
test_max_item = group_by_field(reverse_scripts, 'bnf_name')
assert test_max_item == groups1
```